# Probability space-union of sets

Tags: probability, analysis

Can someone help me with this problem?

We let $(X,A,\lambda)$ be a probability space. We let $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots$ be 
a series of sets in $A$ which satisfy that $\mu(A_n)≥1-1/3^n$.

Then we have to show:
$\mu(⋂^∞_1   A_n)≥1/2$
and conclude that $⋂^∞_1 A_n≠ ø$.

How can I show this? I have tried with $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$ but how can I show it in general?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mu$ (or $\lambda$?) is a probability measure, 
$$
\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = 1-\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c\right) \geq 1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu\left(A_n^c\right)=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{3^n}=\frac12.
$$
The inequality is valid since $\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c\right)\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu\left(A_n^c\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use continuity of probability theorem, namely $$\mathbb{P}[\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i] = \lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}[\cup_{i=1}^nA_i]$$
Now we have $$\mu[\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i] = \mu[(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^c)^c]$$ by De Morgan's laws. Next: $$\mu[(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^c)^c] = 1 - \mu[\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^c]$$ Now, by continuity of probability: $$1 - \mu[\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^c] = 1 -  \lim_{n \to \infty}\mu[\cup_{i=1}^nA_i^c] \geq 1 -  \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\mu[A_i^c] \geq 1 - \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n(1/3^n) = 1/2$$
Inequalities in the end are due to a) probability of a union event is always less or equal than the sum of probabilities of individual events comprising the union, and b) $\mu[A_n] = 1 - \mu[A_n^c] \geq 1 - 1/3^n \implies \mu[A_n^c] \leq 1/3^n$.